# Regex for emoticon

Tags: java, regex

have this regex:

```
(:?^|\s)+(;\))+
```

Im tryng to capture all ocurrences of ;) if it appears alone (between spaces) or at start of line. 
Valid examples

```
;)
 ;) 
;) ;) -> Should be 2 groups of ;)

Dont allow
a;)a
a;) 
;)a
```

Current regex just captures first group for ;) ;) case because second ;) is expecting for a space but its used by first group..

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: What means that? I will use it in a java app.

Comment: So it is Java. It means the language you are using :)

Answer (score 4):

You can match `;)` using lookarounds:

```
(?<=\s|^);\)(?=\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lK4pH9/1)

- `(?<=\s|^)` is look behind that asserts line start or a whitespace is at previous position
- `(?=\s|$)` is look ahead that matches line end or a whitespace is at next position

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s|^);\\)(?=\\s|$)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a more concise lookaround based solution:

```
String rx = "(?x)(?<!\\S)  ;\\)  (?!\\S)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP7gG4/1)

**Explanation**:

- `(?x)` - [COMMENTS modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) ensuring that all pattern whitespace is ignored, and embedded comments starting with `#` are ignored until the end of a line (so that we can better see the parts of the pattern)
- `(?<!\\S)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match if a `;)` is preceded with a non-whitespace char
- `;\\)` - literal `;)`
- `(?!\\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char after the `;)`.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/LlMZfr) with a `replaceAll` to show it finds only those `;)` you need:

```
String s = ";)\n ;) \n;) ;) -> Should be 2 groups of ; )\n\nDont allow\na;)a\na;) \n;)a"; 
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?x)(?<!\\S)  ;\\)  (?!\\S)", "<found>$0</found>"));
```

If you want to further enhance the pattern and you do not feel comfortable with the COMMENTS modifier, remove it. Use `"(?<!\\S);\\)(?!\\S)"` then.